# How does set locale php work? and how can it work with php date?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code: `date("M j, Y", $end);` to display date.

Problem is I've multilingual website, with wordpress + qtranslate.

Now M is problematic as it does not get translated. I read about setlocale php, anyone care explaining how this or if it would work at all?

Or maybe I should find some special qtrnaslate function that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has its own date formating function for international dates, [date_i18n](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n)

Answer (score 0):

From the manual on `date()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and strftime() functions instead of date().